# Using the word "remain" in the question "how many courses do you have?"

Tags: word-usage, usage

How to ask about the rest quantity of courses using the word "remain"?

I mean to ask about If I want to use the word "remain" in the context of the question "how many courses do you have to do in order to get the diploma?" or "How many classes do you have in order to get your final mark?" how can I do that?

I build the following sentence:

> How many courses do you remain?

but it's not clear to me and I'm afraid to use it without verification.

In addition, I don't know how to build an answer using the word "remain" ("remain to me 4 courses to complete" is correct?).

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use the verb *remain* you could use

> How many courses remain in order for me to get the diploma?

A response using *remain* might be

> 4 courses remain in order for you to get the diploma

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I say: "Now remains to me one course only in order to get the bachelor degree"?

Comment: The correct way of saying that would be "Only one course remains now in order for me to get the bachelor degree"